# how to list permission on database level on MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I search for a tsql script to list all permissions granted on database level like this:

```
use SomeDatabase;
GRANT SELECT TO NEWUSER1
```

You can list it by:

```
SETUSER 'NEWUSER1'
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');
```

but I can not find any system view or function (like `sys.database_permissions or sys.server_permissions`) listing this kind of permission.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you looking to use fn_my_permissions for all users in a database

Comment: no, but fn_my_permissions for all logins on the server would do, because I have logins with select rights on databases without being defined as user in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is this what you need.
But you can try this:

```
use yourdatebase;
select sys.schemas.name 'Schema'
   , sys.objects.name Object
   , sys.database_principals.name username
   , sys.database_permissions.type permissions_type
   ,     sys.database_permissions.permission_name
   ,      sys.database_permissions.state permission_state
   ,     sys.database_permissions.state_desc
   ,     state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + '] to [' + sys.database_principals.name + ']' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS 
from sys.database_permissions join sys.objects on sys.database_permissions.major_id =      sys.objects.object_id join sys.schemas on sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id join sys.database_principals on sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id =      sys.database_principals.principal_id order by 1, 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: thanks Fernando, but this doesn't list what I search for. The user is not even listed in sys.database_principals but using SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE') you can see select permission on database level and indeed the user can select on every table.